# How can I refresh website automatically when I design website on VSC?? (HTML)

Tags: web

When I design a website, I usually go back to the page and press f5 to refresh the page, but what I want is for my page to refresh automatically when I change anything on my code without pressing f5

I tried to find help on opera (I'm using opera) and download some extension softwares but It's doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: You want 'Live Server' which will reload a page when you make changes.  I suggest you go to the link below, there is a plugin enabled for Visual Studio Code which allows you to have this feature.

Explanation: The Visual Studio Plugin offers a live server, which can 'host the files' you want to work on, and can watch the file system for any file modifications. Once the Visual Studio Plugin detects a change to the file, the web-server 'reloads' the content automatically.

Go Below to find out how to install the FREE plugin :-)

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/vscode-live-server-auto-refresh-browser/